# logstash 5.2.0 Unable to find JRuby in Mac

Tags: ruby, logstash, jruby

I'm trying to run logstash 5.2.0

```
I downloaded the .tar version from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash
```

When I run:

```
logstash-5.2.0/bin/logstash -f logstash-filter.conf
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to find JRuby.
If you are a user, this is a bug.
If you are a developer, please run 'rake bootstrap'. Running 'rake' requires the 'ruby' program be available.
```

I checked and jruby came with the download. I have this folder in vendor from the downloaded files:

../logstash-5.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9

I'm running in a Mac.

This is the content of logstash-filter.conf

```
input {
    file {
         path => "path/pixel_sample_data.csv"
         start_position => "beginning"
         tags => #array (optional)
         type => #string (optional)
    }
}

filter{
    csv{
        columns =>
    [... colummns ...]
        separator => ","
    }

    date {
        match => ["date","MM-dd-yyyy"]
    }

}

output{
    elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: When do you get that error? Do you want to develop something for logstash or just use logstash?

Comment: I get this error when I try logstash-5.2.0/bin/logstash -f logstash-filter.conf
I just want to use logstash

Comment: Do you have the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable properly defined?

Comment: Yes, my $JAVA_HOME is: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home